# Changing a background image, choosing from other thumbnails - Ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, css, ionic-framework

I need to change a background img when another image thumbnail is clicked.

Currently using Ionic v1 and angular js.

No idea where to start with this one, I'm new to development and this one looks very trick to me.

The thumbnails are shown inside a horizontal scroll and the background stays on top of this scroll.

If anyone have this problem/solution, please help.

This is the div for the background:

`<div class="col imgPerfil" style="background-image:url('img/test/test.jpg');">`

and this is the button with the image I need to change

`<button class="button button-icon botscroll">
      <img src="img/perfil/fotos/fotoscroll01.png" class="imgscroll" ng-model="foto1">
 </button>`

Comment: please post some of the code you have so we can help you.

Comment: Add code to your question to show us what you have tried so far

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know where to start with this one.

But if this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use ng-style

```js
angular.module('test', [])
.controller('test', function ($scope) {
  $scope.image1 = 'http://www.linfield.edu/assets/images/PLACE/place-logo-sm.png';
  $scope.image2 = 'http://www.linfield.edu/assets/images/PLACE/place-logo-sm.png';
  
  $scope.setImage1 = function () {
    $scope.image1 = 'https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/googles-new-logo-5078286822539264.3-hp2x.gif';
  };
  
  $scope.setImage2 = function () {
    $scope.image2 = 'https://privacy.google.com/images/overview/shields.svg';
  };
});
```

```css
div div {
width: 100px; height: 100px;
background-size: cover;
background-position: 50% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="test">
  <button ng-click="setImage1()">Set iamge 1</button>
  <button ng-click="setImage2()">Set iamge 2</button>
  <div ng-style="{'background-image': 'url('+image1+')'}"></div>
  <div ng-style="{'background-image': 'url('+image2+')'}"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hm, I got your idea, but for some reason this is not working. 

The background receives the js line, but it appears that the click function it's not working for me. I see you used a random image selector, could you show an example for fixed images, and not random, please. Thank you so much!

Comment: take a look at example pls

Comment: it was working, but not with my example, because you were using a random selection of images, mine are fixed, but i need to change the url when I click the image, the code needs to push the information from the click.

Comment: How can i make the img2 url push the information on the click?

If I click on image1 it show image1, if I click on image2, it show image2, and goes on.

Comment: Check the new code, in ng-click you must change the image url for whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

I manage to make it work, but when I build de apk, for some reason the images don't show up. This is code:

Background Div:

`<div class="col imgPerfil" ng-style="{'background-image': 'url('+imgback+')'}">`

Image clicked:

`<img src="img/teste/1.jpg" class="imgscroll"  ng-click="changeImg1()">`

JS:

`$scope.imgback = '../img/teste/2.jpg';
  $scope.changeImg1 = function () {
    $scope.imgback = '../img/teste/1.jpg';
  };...`

Is there anything wrong? When I try on livereload, browser or ionic labs, it works, but in the build apk, nothing...

Comment: the images are inside www/img folder?? if yes, change the url to img/test/1.jpg, remove ../ or / from image path

Comment: Yeah, it worked. 

I was assuming it was written like in the css files...

Thank you!